# Sizing UIButton depending on length of titleLabel

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

So I have a UIButton and I'm setting the title in it to a string that is dynamic in length. I want the width of the titleLabel to be half of the screen width. I've tried using .sizeToFit() but this causes the button to use the CGSize before the constraint was applied to the titleLabel. I tried using .sizeThatFits(button.titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize) but this also didn't work. I think the important functions below are the init() & presentCallout(), but I'm showing the entire class just for a more complete understanding. The class I'm playing with looks like:

```
class CustomCalloutView: UIView, MGLCalloutView {
    var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
    
    // Allow the callout to remain open during panning.
    let dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
    let isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true
    
    // https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/9228
    override var center: CGPoint {
        set {
            var newCenter = newValue
            newCenter.y -= bounds.midY
            super.center = newCenter
        }
        get {
            return super.center
        }
    }
    
    lazy var leftAccessoryView = UIView() /* unused */
    lazy var rightAccessoryView = UIView() /* unused */
    
    weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?
    
    let tipHeight: CGFloat = 10.0
    let tipWidth: CGFloat = 20.0
    
    let mainBody: UIButton
    
    required init(representedObject: MGLAnnotation) {
        self.representedObject = representedObject
        self.mainBody = UIButton(type: .system)
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        mainBody.backgroundColor = .white
        mainBody.tintColor = .black
        mainBody.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        mainBody.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        
        addSubview(mainBody)
//        I thought this would work, but it doesn't.
//        mainBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        mainBody.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
//        mainBody.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
//        mainBody.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
//        mainBody.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - MGLCalloutView API
    func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        
        delegate?.calloutViewWillAppear?(self)
        view.addSubview(self)
        
        // Prepare title label.
        mainBody.setTitle(representedObject.title!, for: .normal)
        mainBody.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        mainBody.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        mainBody.sizeToFit()
        
        if isCalloutTappable() {
            // Handle taps and eventually try to send them to the delegate (usually the map view).
            mainBody.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomCalloutView.calloutTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        } else {
            // Disable tapping and highlighting.
            mainBody.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        
        // Prepare our frame, adding extra space at the bottom for the tip.
        let frameWidth = mainBody.bounds.size.width
        let frameHeight = mainBody.bounds.size.height + tipHeight
        let frameOriginX = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width/2.0) - (frameWidth/2.0)
        let frameOriginY = rect.origin.y - frameHeight
        frame = CGRect(x: frameOriginX, y: frameOriginY, width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight)
        
        if animated {
            alpha = 0
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { [weak self] in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                
                strongSelf.alpha = 1
                strongSelf.delegate?.calloutViewDidAppear?(strongSelf)
            }
        } else {
            delegate?.calloutViewDidAppear?(self)
        }
    }
    
    func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {
        if (superview != nil) {
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in
                    self?.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            } else {
                removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Callout interaction handlers
    
    func isCalloutTappable() -> Bool {
        if let delegate = delegate {
            if delegate.responds(to: #selector(MGLCalloutViewDelegate.calloutViewShouldHighlight)) {
                return delegate.calloutViewShouldHighlight!(self)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    @objc func calloutTapped() {
        if isCalloutTappable() && delegate!.responds(to: #selector(MGLCalloutViewDelegate.calloutViewTapped)) {
            delegate!.calloutViewTapped!(self)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Custom view styling
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Draw the pointed tip at the bottom.
        let fillColor: UIColor = .white
        
        let tipLeft = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2.0) - (tipWidth / 2.0)
        let tipBottom = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2.0), y: rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
        let heightWithoutTip = rect.size.height - tipHeight - 1
        
        let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        let tipPath = CGMutablePath()
        tipPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: tipLeft, y: heightWithoutTip))
        tipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipBottom.x, y: tipBottom.y))
        tipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipLeft + tipWidth, y: heightWithoutTip))
        tipPath.closeSubpath()
        
        fillColor.setFill()
        currentContext.addPath(tipPath)
        currentContext.fillPath()
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like for a short title and a long title. When the title gets too long, I want the text to wrap and the bubble to get a taller height. As you can see in the image set below, the first 'Short Name' works fine as a map annotation bubble. When the name gets super long though, it just widens the bubble to the point it goes off the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvlMG.jpg

Any help on how to fix is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is rather confusing... If your button title is `Tap Me`, for example, what do you mean by *"I want the width of the titleLabel to be half of the screen width"*? Can you add a couple images to clarify your goal?

Comment: @DonMag Added images and put the entire class in the body of the question so it's more comprehensive.

Comment: Ah - you want a "multi-line button" ... would have been helpful information when first posting your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable word-wrapping to multiple lines in a `UIButton`, you need to create your own button subclass.

For example:

```
class MultilineTitleButton: UIButton {
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow + 1, for: .vertical)
        self.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow + 1, for: .horizontal)
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = self.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right, height: size.height + contentEdgeInsets.top + contentEdgeInsets.bottom)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel!.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

That button will wrap the title onto multiple lines, cooperating with auto-layout / constraints.

I don't have any projects with MapBox, but here is an example using a modified version of your `CustomCalloutView`. I commented out any MapBox specific code. You *may* be able to un-comment those lines and use this as-is:

```
class CustomCalloutView: UIView { //}, MGLCalloutView {
    //var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
    var repTitle: String = ""
    
    // Allow the callout to remain open during panning.
    let dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
    let isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true
    
    // https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/9228
    
    // NOTE: this causes a vertical shift when NOT using MapBox
//  override var center: CGPoint {
//      set {
//          var newCenter = newValue
//          newCenter.y -= bounds.midY
//          super.center = newCenter
//      }
//      get {
//          return super.center
//      }
//  }
    
    lazy var leftAccessoryView = UIView() /* unused */
    lazy var rightAccessoryView = UIView() /* unused */
    
    //weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?
    
    let tipHeight: CGFloat = 10.0
    let tipWidth: CGFloat = 20.0
    
    let mainBody: UIButton
    var anchorView: UIView!
    
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        if newSuperview == nil {
            anchorView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    //required init(representedObject: MGLAnnotation) {
    required init(title: String) {
        self.repTitle = title
        self.mainBody = MultilineTitleButton()
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        mainBody.backgroundColor = .white
        mainBody.setTitleColor(.black, for: [])
        mainBody.tintColor = .black
        mainBody.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        mainBody.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        
        addSubview(mainBody)
        mainBody.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let padding: CGFloat = 8.0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainBody.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            mainBody.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            mainBody.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            mainBody.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK: - MGLCalloutView API
    func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        
        //delegate?.calloutViewWillAppear?(self)
        
        // since we'll be using auto-layout for the mutli-line button
        //  we'll add an "anchor view" to the superview
        //  it will be removed when self is removed
        anchorView = UIView(frame: rect)
        anchorView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        anchorView.backgroundColor = .clear

        view.addSubview(anchorView)
        
        view.addSubview(self)
        
        // Prepare title label.
        //mainBody.setTitle(representedObject.title!, for: .normal)
        mainBody.setTitle(self.repTitle, for: .normal)
        
//      if isCalloutTappable() {
//          // Handle taps and eventually try to send them to the delegate (usually the map view).
//          mainBody.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomCalloutView.calloutTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
//      } else {
//          // Disable tapping and highlighting.
//          mainBody.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
//      }
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        anchorView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchorView.centerXAnchor),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchorView.topAnchor),
            self.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: constrainedRect.width),
        ])

        
        if animated {
            alpha = 0
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { [weak self] in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                
                strongSelf.alpha = 1
                //strongSelf.delegate?.calloutViewDidAppear?(strongSelf)
            }
        } else {
            //delegate?.calloutViewDidAppear?(self)
        }
    }
    
    func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {
        if (superview != nil) {
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in
                    self?.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            } else {
                removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Callout interaction handlers
    
//  func isCalloutTappable() -> Bool {
//      if let delegate = delegate {
//          if delegate.responds(to: #selector(MGLCalloutViewDelegate.calloutViewShouldHighlight)) {
//              return delegate.calloutViewShouldHighlight!(self)
//          }
//      }
//      return false
//  }
//
//  @objc func calloutTapped() {
//      if isCalloutTappable() && delegate!.responds(to: #selector(MGLCalloutViewDelegate.calloutViewTapped)) {
//          delegate!.calloutViewTapped!(self)
//      }
//  }
    
    // MARK: - Custom view styling
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print(#function)
        // Draw the pointed tip at the bottom.
        let fillColor: UIColor = .red
        
        let tipLeft = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2.0) - (tipWidth / 2.0)
        let tipBottom = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width / 2.0), y: rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
        let heightWithoutTip = rect.size.height - tipHeight - 1
        
        let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        let tipPath = CGMutablePath()
        tipPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: tipLeft, y: heightWithoutTip))
        tipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipBottom.x, y: tipBottom.y))
        tipPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: tipLeft + tipWidth, y: heightWithoutTip))
        tipPath.closeSubpath()
        
        fillColor.setFill()
        currentContext.addPath(tipPath)
        currentContext.fillPath()
    }
}
```

Here is a sample view controller showing that "Callout View" with various length titles, restricted to 70% of the width of the view:

```
class CalloutTestVC: UIViewController {

    let sampleTitles: [String] = [
        "Short Title",
        "Slightly Longer Title",
        "A ridiculously long title that will need to wrap!",
    ]
    var idx: Int = -1
    
    let tapView = UIView()

    var ccv: CustomCalloutView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8939146399, green: 0.8417750597, blue: 0.7458069921, alpha: 1)
        
        tapView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        tapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tapView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tapView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            tapView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            tapView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            tapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tapView.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        // tap the Blue View to cycle through Sample Titles for the Callout View
        //  using the Blue view as the "anchor rect"
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap))
        tapView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }

    @objc func gotTap() -> Void {
        if ccv != nil {
            ccv.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // increment sampleTitles array index
        //  to cycle through the strings
        idx += 1
        
        let validIdx = idx % sampleTitles.count
        
        let str = sampleTitles[validIdx]
        
        // create a new Callout view
        ccv = CustomCalloutView(title: str)
        
        // to restrict the "callout view" width to less-than 1/2 the screen width
        //      use view.width * 0.5 for the constrainedTo width
        // may look better restricting it to 70%
        ccv.presentCallout(from: tapView.frame, in: self.view, constrainedTo: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width * 0.7, height: 100), animated: false)
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `UIButton` class owns the `titleLabel` and is going to position and set the constraints on that label itself.  More likely than not you are going to have to create a subclass of `UIButton` and override its "updateConstraints" method to position the `titleLabel` where you want it to go.

Your code should probably not be basing the size of the button off the size of the screen.  It might set the size of off some other view in your hierarchy that happens to be the size of the screen but grabbing the screen bounds in the middle of setting a view's size is unusual.

Comment: Hi Scott, to be honest, the 'half screen width' was arbitrary. The width of the view can be some fixed value, like 400 or so. With that specification, is there an easier solution than subclassing UIButton?

Comment: Not really... because the button owns the `titleLabel` and is responsible for positioning it.  Unless you override the framework it's going to do that.